# Detect Facebook as referrer?

Tags: php, facebook, referrer

I have this closed-beta website that disables normal visits - visitors have to log in first to view the site. I have a secret Facebook group also, in which we often share the links to the website articles (for discussion). Problem is, when we paste a link, Facebook tries to get its preview and fails, since it's considered a non-logged in user. So in short, I'd want the website is public **only to Facebook**. These are the solutions I've come up with:

1. Detect the referrer: Fails, the referrer is empty - maybe because FB browses the site from HTTPs?
2. Detect client IP: Not sure about this. Does FB server have a fixed IP address?
3. Search about a "Facebook query string" that FB uses when browses my site - something like mysite.com/?from=I'm-Facebook-Bitch: No results so far.

What do you think? Is there a reliable way to accomplish this mission? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I've found the solution here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Instead of checking for IP or referrer, we can check for the user agent (`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`) of the FB scraper. The value is `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: If this was your solution, please be sure to mark it as the correct answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you post a 'secret' link to the 'closed' Facebook group. The link is unique, and if you visit that link you DONT need to be logged in.

Then Facebook can access without any secret voodoo magic - and the 'closed' group have access to the article.

For example:

```
www.example.com/articles/my-article   <- you need to be logged in to see this

www.example.com/special-hidden-link/special-hidden-article   <- no login required
```

So just post the "hidden link" to the Facebook group - and they can all see the article

Comment: Thanks, but this is actually more voodoo than a real solution. I can't expect all group members (most are not tech savy) to add a param into the URLs.

Comment: I dont think you understood - see my example.

Comment: Also - this is basically the only solution - because if you post a "link" on Facebook - anyone (including facebook) needs to be able to get to that link without logging in - that is your whole issue. So whether you have refeer tags etc or not - you are basically saying that the facebook people get to see the article...

Comment: Actually all the Facebook group guys still have to log in. So it's only the Facebook spider that I need to cater about. I understand your solution, but unfortunately custom link generation is not an option, since we're using a CMS and such requires a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Add a GET argument as a key to visit the website, and set a cookie once the key is found valid.